# How to enable UDP protocol in curl?

Tags: curl, udp

Probably a dumb question, but how to enable UDP in curl on a Ubuntu server? I'm trying to set up a torrent tracker but its unable to scrape from any other trackers. When I run the Curl command with any UDP url in SSH Putty it gives the following message:

Protocol UDP not supported or disabled in libcurl

Answer (score 6):

Nothing's a dumb question if it means you'll learn from it. When I look at the [cURL homepage](http://curl.haxx.se/), I don't see UDP as a listed protocol. And the resources online don't return many relevant results from what I can see.

Have you considered looking into anything for connecting to sockets?

Not sure how extensive your language knowledge base is, but here's a tutorial to consider:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-sock2/

Additionally, [NodeJS UDP](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html) might have a smaller learning curve depending on what you're familiar with.

Comment: Update in 2020: http3-QUIC uses udp